# Replacing AppAuth with custom SFSafariViewController in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

i want to replace appauth with custom SFSafariViewController for login and getting back token from web.Can anyone help me how to proceed with this with some example or and tutorial.

As i am beginner to iOS development I am not sure where to start.Thanks.

AppAuth - https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS

Answer (score 0):

The login is not performed in a SFSafariViewController but with a ASWebAuthenticationSession. It is not possible to override the Safari view for an ASWebAuthenticationSession (it is an OS feature).

If you implement yourself the OpenID flow in a custom SFSafariViewController, you will need to declare the callback URL in your info.plist file and AppDelegate. It will be less secure and less user friendly.